# I am getting varchar to numeric error?

Tags: sql-server

What I am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this, breaking out length and with from a string and converting it to an numeric value?

```
UPDATE VF_CasINV_Cost
   SET TotWgt = CASE
        WHEN (Dimension like '%x%') THEN
        (cast(left(Dimension, charindex('X', Dimension, 1) - 1) as numeric))  *
        (cast(substring(Dimension, 1 + charindex('X', Dimension, 1), len(Dimension)) as numeric)) / 144.00

        WHEN TotWgt = 0 and [Wt/Ft]  > 0 THEN  (Dimension * [Wt/Ft]) * [Count]
        WHEN TotWgt = 0 and [Wt/Sht] > 0 THEN ((Dimension * [Wt/Sht]) / 100) * [Count]
        WHEN TotWgt = 0 and [Wt/Pc]  > 0 THEN ((Dimension * [Wt/Pc] ) / 100) * [Count]
        ELSE TotWgt
    END --TotWgt, Item#, TotWgt, [Wt/Ft], [Wt/Sht], [Wt/Pc], [Count], Dimension, TotWgt
FROM VF_CasINV_Cost
WHERE (CalendarYear = 2010) AND (Item# = Item#) AND (ID = ID) AND (Item# < 99999990)
AND K = 'K' AND D = '' AND C = '' AND (Unit = 'cwt' OR Unit = 'cwts')
```

Comment: You have GOT to simplify this. We have no idea what your schema is like, what text strings are being processed, etc. etc.

Comment: You should provide a table schema so it will be obvious which column of which type is

Answer (score 0):

I'll make some assumptions: Dimension is a varchar field; you are trying to parse out the numeric value out of this varchar field and use it in calculations.
If so, your problem is last three WHEN cases: you are using Dimension in multiplication operations without casting it. so SQL can't perform multiplication on a varchar field.

Comment: When they are that easy to see, it seems they are the hardest 
to find.  Thanks!  made the the changes:


        WHEN TotWgt = 0 and [Wt/Ft]  > 0 THEN  (cast(Dimension as numeric) * [Wt/Ft]) * [Count]
    WHEN TotWgt = 0 and [Wt/Sht] > 0 THEN ((cast(Dimension as numeric) * [Wt/Sht]) / 100) * [Count]
        WHEN TotWgt = 0 and [Wt/Pc]  > 0 THEN ((cast(Dimension as numeric) * [Wt/Pc] ) / 100) * [Count]

But I still get the varchar to numeric error?

Comment: if Dimension is something like "d1782" you will get the error. You have to parse the numeric value from string and then perform the cast